# customizing apa style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I am trying to create a document where **citations** follow the **authoryear** styling and **bibliography** follows the **apa**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=99}
\usepackage{csquotes}
 \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib} 
@article{citation01,
Author = {LastName1, FirstName1 and LastName2, FirstName2 and LastName3, FirstName3 and LastName4, FirstName4 and LastName5, FirstName5 and LastName6, FirstName6 and LastName7, FirstName7 and LastName8, FirstName8},
Journal = {A journal name},
Number = {3},
Pages = {22--38},
Title = {A Title name},
Volume = {4},
Year = {2011}}
 @article{citation02,
Author = {LastName1, FirstName1 and LastName2, FirstName2 and LastName3, FirstName3 and LastName4, FirstName4 and LastName5, FirstName5 and LastName6, FirstName6 and LastName7, FirstName7 and LastName8, FirstName8},
Journal = {A journal name2},
Number = {3},
Pages = {22--38},
Title = {A Title name2},
Volume = {4},
Year = {2011}}

\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{citation01} and \textcite{citation02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The output of the above file is:[image: output]

1) The full author list is not generated at the bibliography section.

2)

- One option I tried was changing maxcitenames (setting it to 1).
- Another option was using citestyle (=authoryear) and bibstyle (=apa) while loading.

Both of them failed.

Citation desired would be

> LastName1 et al. (2011a) and LastName1
>   et al. (2011b)

and bibliography would include the full author list.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So you want to use APA style package to conflict with what the APA style guide says about author lists?

Comment: @Seamus Well many people require APA style in spirit, not letter.

Answer (score 7):

From the `biblatax-apa` manual: (p.6)

> The `\maxprtauth` commands returns the
>   number of author/editor names which
>   are printed. APA style defaults to 7.
>   You can reset this after loading biblatex with, for example,
>   `\renewcommand{\maxprtauth}{25}` if
>   you really want to fully print all
>   author list references in certain
>   contexts (for example in a CV where
>   you are an author in position 8 ...)

So the solution to your problem is to add

`\renewcommand{\maxprtauth}{99}`

to your document.

You should be aware that the format that `biblatex-apa` uses is the one required by the APA.

Comment: this solves the bibliography limitation! any workaround about the citations, aka make them look like authoryear ?

Comment: @gkotsis On your test document, I get the *et al.* as well. Do you not?

Comment: nope, I am getting: “A Title name” (2011a) and “A Title name2” (2011b).

Comment: @gkotsis Are you using the latest versions of biblatex and biblatex-apa?